# Repair WMI on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wmi

I had a problem with my Microsoft SQL Server 2008, importing data and generating scripts, so I decided to uninstall it.  When I tried to remove it, I got an error from the check screen.  The WMI service is corrupted, so I need a way to reset the WMI service.

Platform: Windows 7 64bit

I did try `winmgmt /resetrepository`

to no effect.

Short of reinstalling Windows, what can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If its a file level corruption you could probably try the `sfc /scannow` command - this will check and replace any system files that are damaged.

Answer (score 6):

To fully rebuild the WMI Repository follow these steps:

1. Disable and stop the winmgmt service.
2. Remove or rename `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\repository`.
3. Enable and start the winmgmt service.
4. Open a cmd prompt as Administrator.
5. In the cmd prompt navigate to `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\`
6. Run the command `for /f %s in ('dir /b *.mof') do mofcomp %s` This will take a minute or so to complete.
7. Run the command `for /f %s in ('dir /b en-us\*.mfl') do mofcomp en-us\%s`

Comment: helped me on windows 10

Comment: Thanks! Executing these steps helped me to solve the Sourcetree startup problem on Windows 7 Pro 64bit (caused by WMI problem) described here:  https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Sourcetree-installer-Failed-to-start-System-Management/qaq-p/2196885

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and using Repair WMI from [Tweaking.com](http://www.tweaking.com/content/page/repair_wmi.html) fixed it.

Comment: The tool mentioned in this answer fixed the issue for me & as a bonus got the question re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

Another handy option to fix WMI using a WMI Fixer Tool ([WMI Fixer.ps1)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/WMI-Fixer-Tool-4c8dd60f/file/117827/1/WMI%20Fixer.ps1)  created by [Guido Basilio de Oliviera](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/WMI-Fixer-Tool-4c8dd60f) and is freely available.

This tool is based on Windows Powershell and Windows Forms:

```
cd /d % windir% \System32\Wbem
net stop winmgmt

winmgmt /clearadap
winmgmt /kill
winmgmt /unregserver
winmgmt /regserver
winmgmt /resyncperf

del % windir% \System32\Wbem\Repository /Q
del % windir% \System32\Wbem\AutoRecover /Q

for % % i in (* .dll) do Regsvr32 -s % % i
for % % i in (* .mof, * .mfl) do Mofcomp % % i
wmiadap.exe /Regsvr32
wmiapsrv.exe /Regsvr32
wmiprvse.exe /Regsvr32

net start winmgmt
```

---

Or alternatively..

- Disable and stop the WMI service.
- Run the following commands.

  `Winmgmt /salvagerepository %windir%\System32\wbem`

  (then)

  `Winmgmt /resetrepository %windir%\System32\wbem`
- Re-enable the WMI service and then reboot the PC to see how it goes.

  **You could also try rebuilding the repository if the above fails:**
- Disable and stop the WMI service.
- Rename the repository folder (located at `%windir%\System32\wbem\repository`) to repository.old.
- Re-enable the WMI service.
- Reboot the PC

Acknowledgements

1. [WMI corrupt - how to reinstall/repair?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/8ed26d46-9994-4052-a307-5b071805aea8/wmi-corrupt-how-to-reinstallrepair?forum=winservergen)

Answer (score 0):

I run into corrupt WMI fairly often working with client systems.  I was very frustrated by the acknowledgement from MS that WMI has issues and not getting releif with any suggested fix.

Last year I found this procedure and it works EVERY TIME!

Open a Microsoft PowerShell window. 
Type the following commands and press enter after each command

```
net stop winmgmt
ren c:\windows\system32\wbem\repository  c:\windows\system32\wbem\repository_old
net start winmgmt 
cd c:\windows\system32\wbem
lodctr /r
```

Check and make sure all services are running.  A reboot is not required at this point, but it is the fastest way to assure that all services restart.